# Is there a UV-VIS spectral database for common materials?

Tags: material-science, spectroscopy, optical-materials

Looking for a database of spectral data in the **ultraviolet to visible range** (interested in roughly 200 to 800 nm) for common materials found in homes, vehicles, mass transportation, factories, etc.  In other words, things like various cloth types, various metals, plastics, etc.

There are a number of spectral databases for chemical compounds and even the kinds of manmade materials I am after.  However, none of the ones I found cover anything below the IR range.  For example, I found a library with lots of materials of interest but they all start at 2 micrometers.

Comment: This question would fit well on the new [Materials Modeling SE](https://materials.stackexchange.com/#)

Comment: There is also a "databses" tag on the Materials Modeling Stack Exchange.